# «Те, кого помню». Нужна запятая перед «кого» или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

> Те(,) кого помню.

Нужна запятая перед «кого» или нет?

Answer (score 3):

***Те, кого помню.*** Запятая нужна.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение (или его фрагмент): до запятой – главная часть, после – придаточная.

[***Сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными определительными***](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#42101)

> ...существуют придаточные определительные предложения, относящиеся именно к указательным или определительным местоимениям *тот, то, таков, такой, каждый, весь, всякий* и др., которые не могут быть опущены. Такие придаточные называются **местоименно-определительными**. Средства связи в них — относительные местоимения *кто, что, какой, каков, который*.

Примеры подобных предложений можно посмотреть [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%82%D0%B5%2C+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).